# RecyclerView is unreachable

Tags: android

I'm learning `RecyclerView` and having trouble with my recycler:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/bootik_recycler"
    />
```

And the class:

```
public class BotikFragment extends Fragment {

  private RecyclerView recyclerView;
  private View view;

  @Nullable
  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

   View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_botik,container);

     return view;
     recyclerView=(RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.bootik_recycler);
```

I'm getting an `Unreachable Statement` error.

Comment: Welcome to the community. You may wish to attach error logs as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put the last two statements in different order:

```
recyclerView=(RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.bootik_recycler);
return view;
```

Comment: @Mohsen it's important that you understand why this is happening. `return view;` means the method will stop executing after this line. Therefore any code below this line is unreachable.